How to migrate from DynamoDB to Timestream
I have a collection of historical IoT data stored in DynamoDB. Due to DynamoDB's limit per query, I'm facing challenges in performing analytics queries. I'm considering migrating this data from DynamoDB to Timestream to improve query performance. However, I couldn't find any documentation, blog, or guides on migrating data specifically from DynamoDB to Timestream. Can someone provide guidance or point me to relevant resources? Thank you.

The way to get data into Timestream is via BatchLoad which expects CSV

Data source – The source CSV file that is stored in an S3 bucket. For information about preparing the data file, see Preparing a batch load data file. For information about S3 pricing, see Amazon S3 pricing

Depending on the amount of data in DynamoDB you can do a number of things:

Write your own script to Scan the data and use your scripting language to store on S3. Good for small data.
Large data you can read from DynamoDB and store in S3 in CSV format.

